# Word 2013 - How to create a new table style from an existing table style?

Tags: formatting, microsoft-word-2013, styles, layout

In Word 2013, lets say I have a few table layouts.   For example

[image: word table]
[image: word tables example2]

Is there any way to create a new table style via the Design tab based on my existing table design, or am I forced to try to emulate this table design by creating a new style that mimics my current table design?   I cannot seem to find any way to create a new table style based on my existing table formatting.

Comment: Are you looking for [How to save Table Templates in Word 2013](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/table-templates-word) ?

Comment: That might just work!  I will try when I get back to work.  In the meantime, go ahead and post your comment as the answer so I can award the bounty.

Comment: Yep you got it!   Thank you so much..   Could Microsoft choose a worse place to put this function?   Why not in the design tab when you have a table selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the article [How to save Table Templates in Word 2013](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/table-templates-word)
describes how to set up a table-template from an existing table :

1. Select the table
2. In the `Insert` tab click the small drop-down arrow residing below the Table icon to display the menu
3. Select `Quick Tables` and on the right `Save selection to Quick Tables Gallery`
4. In the window `Create New Building Block`, give your new table template a name
5. Click OK to save

To insert the table template in the document,
go to the `Insert` tab -> `Table` -> `Quick Table`.

Comment: This is not so much how to create a new table **STYLE** (i.e., a mechanism by which a set of design characteristics can be applied to an existing table). It is a way to generate a *template* that applies styles when *new tables* are **created**. Not the same thing, really. As far as I can tell, the only way to create a custom table **style** is to go through one of 2 GPITA tasks: creating one from scratch, or modifying an existing one. Both are the sort of thing that nobody wants to do... thus garmonbozia is created.

Comment: @GT., what is GPITA?... garmonbozia also sounds interesting :P

Comment: See [garmonbozia](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Garmonbozia). Everyone knows what [PITA](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pita) is, but not GPITA. It might mean "Great PITA".

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new table style or modify an existing one by doing the following:

1. Select the table
2. Select **Design** under **Table Tools**
3. Click the drop-down on the bottom right of the **Design** menu
4. At the bottom there is the choice of **Modify Table Style**, **Clear**, and **New Table Style**.
5. If you choose **New Table Style** you can base it on an existing table style.
6. You can find out the name of the existing table styles by hovering over the table style.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  He wants to base it on an existing table... not an existing table style.